# Time machine backups on external HDD over WiFi

Tags: time-machine

I like to do backups via Time Machine since my TimeCapsule vaporized after 3 years of service. It's only the power supply which is broken but Apple can't fix it they tell me in an Apple Store. A *little* ridicolous, but anyway...

I like to use a normal USB HDD to do my backups now and I like to plug that into my router so I can do it via WiFi. Problem: My router (and a short research of mine says it is not only my router) is not able to deal with Mac OS Extended format. He only recognizes FAT and NTSF. Time Machine however always asks to reformat the HDD to Mac OS Extended. I read an article about how to deal with that but it is kinda out of date and didn't work under Mountain Lion. So my question:

Is there a way of getting Time Machine using a FAT formatted HDD to make backups on?

Comment: AFAIK, Time Machine depends on some features (hard links) of the filesystem that FAT does not provide

Comment: How does the router share the disk - ie which protocol does the Mac mount the disk under? Which router is it most can't connect to USX drives as they only do network connections

Comment: @DavidPearce I just read (a german) blog entry from 2010 where they explained that the feature to use FAT drives was disabled by Apple but could be enabled. But if you say so, it seems that Time Machine does not provide that capability any more.

Comment: @Mark I can see the USB HDD in finder IF it is formatted as FAT 32. IF it is not, I can't see the HDD. I could be able to get access via FTP I guess. And I don't know what a USX drive is...

Comment: SOrry USX was a typo

Comment: HFS+ (aka Mac OS Extended) isn't strictly required but is the only format Apple officially supports. Network-based Time Machine backups use Disk Images, so the underlying capabilities of the file format don't matter. However, there is some underlying mDNS metadata that the remote device typically needs to broadcast for OS X to understand it as an appropriate backup destination. The unfortunate answer is that you may not be able to get reliable backups working through this router. What brand & model of router do you have?

Comment: @bispymusic I'm not quite sure if it is the brand, but it's a Vodafone EasyBox 802.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Capsule (networked Time Machine) relies on the share being AFP.  If you can get your router to share the file via AFP everything should work.  My guess is that that will take quite a bit of work though.  You might start with DD-WRT.

Comment: I have a Vodafone EasyBox 802. How can I check if this is supported by DD-WRT? It is not listed in their router database... Does this already mean it is not supported or is it because Vodafone is not the manufacturer?

Comment: DD-WRT is hours and hours of work with unless you're working with a specific set of routers, and the likelyhood is that your router doesn't support it.  You're probably better off replacing your power supply manually, though that's obviously an undertaking of itself.  If I were in your shoes I would consider these my only viable options: 1) get a new TC;  2) replace the power supply of the existing one manually; 3) put together a linux box with USB of some sort (DD-WRT on a supported router would be enough) and install netatalk; 4) find another AFP-capable server; #3 is not for faint of heart.

Comment: Hi. 1) Too expansive (+ lost faith in Apple products lately). 2) I guess I could try that but I have another quest: I like to have access to my computer via internet from work. I like to do wake-on-demand which lead me to DD-WRT anyway... 3) That's what I like to try, although I don't know netatalk. 4) No. Question: With a router and DD-WRT, would that be able to mount a HFS+ HDD? Or does that rely on hardware?

Comment: See this page for USB support on DDWRT:http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/USB  Good luck!